# Inactive employees in Office365 and MySites

Tags: office-365, active-directory, my-site

Today one of the users that use the intranet (Office365) asked us about a few employees that are inactive in Active Directory but they still appear if someone search for them in MySites. We have developed a webpart so that the users could search for employees without have to look in MySites. They can search for a name, a work phone or a department, and then they can see those employees.

The problem is that after Sharepoint synchronizes with Active Directory, the user complained that some inactive employees are appearing at employees's search on the intranet and also in MySites.

Particulary I do not know could I do to prevent these users to be displayed when Sharepoint Synchronizes with Active Directory. Where can I set up this thing?

Comment: I looked in Office365 Central Administration and saw something strange. I found some users that appear in MySites, but if I look for them in Central Administration, I do not see any of them. I looked at the search of both the active and inactive user. Is this possible? It is possible that I may have users who are not active or inactive, but they can be displayed in MySites? In the search for active users saw many users who have different status.

Comment: Some have a status like this: Synchronized with Active Directory, as other users have a status as: At Cloud. My second question would be: After SharePoint synchronizes with Active Directory and these users appear in the Intranet, MySites etc, if I delete these users, they also should not be excluded from the intranet just like from MySites?

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing more from your post, my guess is that these inactive users in AD still have profiles in Office 365 and assigned licenses. So you need to delete these users, free their licenses (happens upon deletion), and await the 30 day grace period. Within those 30 days, you can fully restore these deleted users and their content. So these inactive users can still show up in search results during this grace period. After the 30 days and the following crawl – your problem will be permanently resolved.

> If a user no longer needs licenses, like when an employee leaves an organization, you can delete that user’s account. When you do this, any licenses that were assigned to that person become available to assign to another user.
>
> **IMPORTANT** When you delete a user account, it becomes inactive. During this inactive period, you have up to 30 days to fully restore the account. After 30 days, all data for that user is permanently deleted—except documents saved on SharePoint Online. Delete users only if you are certain that they won’t need this data in the future.
>
> To delete the account for one or more users
>
> 1. Sign in to Office 365 with your work or school account.
> 2. Go to the Office 365 admin center.
> 3. Select Users > Active Users (or Users & groups > Add users, reset passwords, and more).
> 4. Select the name of the user or multiple users that you want to delete, and then click Delete.
>
> [image]
>
> 5. In the confirmation box, click yes.

Reference: [Assign or unassign licenses for Office 365 for business - Delete a user account to free a license](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Assign-or-remove-licenses-for-Office-365-business-997596b5-4173-4627-b915-36abac6786dc#BKMKDeleteUser)